# Apache: property for minimum amount of requests

Tags: apache, tomcat, server, configuration

I have multiple Tomcats instances on a Apache Server and I use load balancer but my instances switch from A to B to C and back to A after each request, I want to switch from one instance to another after some amount of request is taken by a specific Tomcat, is there a property for that in workers.property file?

Comment: Do you mean you have Apache `httpd` in front of Tomcat?

Comment: That is correct.